# How to convert a Mongo FilterDefinition from a class to a BsonDocument

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to find a way to convert a Mongo FilterDefinition to FilterDefinition in C#.  Is .ToBsonDocument() enough or is there a more efficient way of doing it?

At the repository level I want to make all collections just BsonDocuments,  So something like this would work

Builders..Filter.EQ("FirstName", "Chad")

What I would like to do is allow 
Builds..Filter.EQ(x => x.FirstName, "Chad)

to be passed into the method and convert the FilterDefinition to FilterDefinition so I can do some added filtering on the returning values.

Comment: I think an example would be very helpful

Comment: updated with some more details

Comment: You can generic Builders to strongly type cast like this Builders<YourClassName>.Filter.EQ(x => x.FirstName)